# Minimum number of levels in an n-ary tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree

I understand intuitively why in a binary tree there are a minimum of floor(log<sub>2</sub>(n)) + 1 levels. I was wondering if there is an equivalently straightforward algorithm for the minimum number of levels in an n-ary tree. Say a full/complete ternary tree for example: my intuition tells me this would involve log<sub>3</sub>(n) somehow but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the formula for an *m*-ary tree by first checking what the maximum number of nodes is that you can store in a tree with degree *m*:

| levels | *n* |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1+*m* |
| 3 | 1+*m*+*m²* |
| 4 | 1+*m*+*m*²+*m*³ |
| ... | ... |
| *k* | 1+*m*+*m*²+...+*m*<sup>*k*−1</sup> |

This is [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) to

*n* = (*m*<sup>*k*</sup> − 1) / (*m* − 1)

This means that a tree with *k* levels has at least *n* = 1 + (*m*<sup>*k*−1</sup> − 1) / (*m* − 1) nodes. Solve that to *k*:

*n* = 1 + (*m*<sup>*k*−1</sup> − 1) / (*m* − 1)
      *n* − 1 = (*m*<sup>*k*−1</sup> − 1) / (*m* − 1)
      (*n* − 1)(*m* − 1) = *m*<sup>*k*−1</sup> − 1
      (*n* − 1)(*m* − 1) + 1 = *m*<sup>*k*−1</sup>
      log<sub>*m*</sub>((*n* − 1)(*m* − 1) + 1) = *k* − 1
      log<sub>*m*</sub>((*n* − 1)(*m* − 1) + 1) + 1 = *k*

As *n* is here a minimum of nodes for *k* levels, we need to take the floor when *n* is free:

*k* = <sub>⌊</sub>log<sub>*m*</sub>((*n* − 1)(*m* − 1) + 1)<sub>⌋</sub> + 1

For binary trees, *m*=2, so that simplifies to:

*k* = <sub>⌊</sub>log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)<sub>⌋</sub> + 1

...which is what you already had.

For ternary trees, *m*=3, so then we get:

*k* = <sub>⌊</sub>log<sub>3</sub>(2*n* − 1)<sub>⌋</sub> + 1

Comment: Thanks, that was an excellent explanation. Maths is not my strong suit but was able to follow along with this completely. Only question would be, what do you mean when you say "n is free"? I understand why take the floor here, just not the usage of the term free, in this context.

Comment: I say "free", because we started choosing *n* based on specific values of *k*. *n* could not be just *any* value, only specific values. At the paragraph *"This means that..."* we defined *n* as a *minimum* number of nodes. But once the formula is turned around, *n* no longer needs to have the meaning "minimum number of nodes": it can be "freed" to mean "number of nodes". And then you need the flooring.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. Small thing: I think you meant to say _degree m_ instead of _level m_ before the table?

Comment: Yes, indeed! Corrected.